# Problem using Flask 2.0.0 with jython gradle plugin

Tags: android, flask, android-gradle-plugin, jython

I am new to android development, but not to programming. I am expert with python but newer to java, so I used the jython gradle plugin. In my main.py, I have the following code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hello world"

if name == "main":
    app.run(debug=False, port=8118)
```

Then in my java code, I create a webview and load the url "http://localhost:8118". But it throws the error,

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
```

I think the jython plugin fails to create the flask app and run it in the android phone and access it in the webview, but I'm not certain and it could be another problem.
In my build.gradle( Project ):

```
task testJython(type:jython.JythonTask) {
  jython{
    pypackage 'Flask:2.0.0'
  }
  script file("C:/Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/my-app-name/app/src/main/assets/main.py")
}
```

My main.py is in the assets folder. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Android's primary programming languages are Kotlin and Java, there is no known port of Jython to the platform.

To build apps for Android you need to interact with the UI engine. you can build native apps with *Java* or *Kotlin*.
For Cross-platform and other programming languages you can use *Dart* with *Flutter* (Google's UI toolkit), *JavaScript* with React Native, Apache Cordova with *HTML*, *CSS* and *JavaScript* or Xamarin with *C#*

Create and run Python apps on your Android phone https://opensource.com/article/20/8/python-android-mobile

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understood why you want to use jython for android development with flask.
What I understood is that you want to develop an android app and in the backend you want to use flask, so create an api(either rest or graphql) using flask and use it in your android project. Learn some tutorials on android project how to use rest api/graphql api in android project. Since, you are good in flask you must be knowing how to create a rest api or graphql api , if not learn that too.

May following tutorials will help you
There are very basic, but enough to grasp the workflow
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-make-client-android-application-with-flask-for-server-side-8b1d5c55446e

https://github.com/ahmedfgad/AndroidFlask